# How to define "node" type in roslyn?

Tags: c#, roslyn

I have a code:

```
public override void VisitMemberAccessExpression(MemberAccessExpressionSyntax node)
{                        
    Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}", node.Name);
}
```

How can I define a node type? For example: if node type is "Product" so do not write it.

Answer (score 3):

As its name implies, `MemberAccessExpressionSyntax` contains only the syntactic information about the expression, which does not include anything about types.

If you want to get the type information, you will need to create a `Compilation` for your syntax tree (or trees) and get its `SemanticModel`. With that, you can do something like:

```
semanticModel.GetTypeInfo(node).Type.Name == "Product"
```