# SyntaxWalker Visit method

Tags: c#, roslyn

I Have a problem with class SyntaxWalker and method:

```
VisitMemberAccessExpression(MemberAccessExpressionSyntax node)
```

I would like get node type and if equal for example: "Person" add to List.
I use:

```
if(semanticModel.GetTypeInfo(node).Type.Name == modelName)
list.Add("Stack");
```

but I have error: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" why?
My fields:

```
private ISemanticModel semanticModel;
public string modelName { get; private set; }
```

Set model name:

```
modelName = type.BaseType.TypeArguments[0].Name.ToString();
```

I've been on it for a few days and do not know what to do please help please.
I do this in accordance with the advice:
[How to define "node" type in roslyn?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17448094/how-to-define-node-type-in-roslyn)

Comment: It' hard to help you based just on those few snippets. Can you post a short, but complete sample code that demonstrates your issue?

Comment: What nodes are you trying to collect? `MemberAccessExpressionSyntax` or `ClassDeclarationSyntax` or some other type of nodes?

Comment: @AlexFilipovici I want to chose only those nodes whose type is specified in the "ModelName". I think the whole point of this ClassDeclarationSyntax..

svick I full code:
http://pastebin.com/vdM5hvQq

Comment: Anyway I want to write to your viewProperties only those in whose type.AnyProp type == ModelName type ..

Comment: I also find myself wondering, you're asking a lot of questions in this area, but seems to be finding none of the answers helpful. Is this generally the case, or could you maybe indicate by means of an upvote those you find most helpful?